# The moment of inertia of a hollow cylinder is lower than that of the "corresponding" solid cylinder (same density, outer radius, height):

Tags: density, inertia, moment

This is a self-answered "question" for those scratching their heads after learning, e.g. in class, that the moment of inertia of a hollow cylinder is higher than that of solid cylinder. Note that I phrased this differently than above, and not only in that the result is the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this makes sense. Moment of inertia is a measure of how far from the rotation axis a mass is concentrated. A hollow tube has its mass concentrated as far away from possible from the center. A solid tube has its mass distributed evenly at every radius.

As a result for two shapes *of the same mass* $m$, and outside radius $R$, have different coefficients of mass distribution.

The thin hollow tube has

$$ I_{\rm thin} = 1\,m R^2 $$

and the solid rod

$$ I_{\rm solid} = \tfrac{1}{2} m R^2 $$

The in-between state, again with an outside radius $R$, but with a hollow center of radius $r$ has mass moment of inertia

$$ I_{\rm tube} =m \left( \frac{ r^2 + R^2}{2} \right) $$

and you can see how when $r$ ranges between $r=0 \ldots R$ it approaches either of the expressions above.

This becomes more evident if you consider the parameter $\lambda = \left(r/R\right)^2$ and express the above as

$$ I_{\rm tube} = (1-\lambda) I_{\rm solid} + (\lambda) I_{\rm thin} $$

Clearly, the MMOI of a tube is a linear interpolation of the two extreme values with the interpolation parameter $\lambda$ the ratio of areas between the hollow center and the overall area.

So to think of MMOI intuitively think about how is the mass distributed around the center and how close it is to a thin solid or a solid shape. The same applies to all other shapes too, and often you will see in tables of MMOI the solid version and the thin version for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

The following may (or may not) have occurred: The moment of inertia of a hollow cylinder was derived via an integral and the following expression was found:

$I_{hollow\ cylinder}\ =\ \frac{m}{2}(r_{inner}^2+r_{outer}^2)$

This is then compared to the moment of inertia of a solid cylinder by removing the term for the inner radius:

$I_{solid\ cylinder}\ =\ \frac{m}{2}(r_{outer}^2)$

and it is noted that the moment of inertia of the hollow cylinder is higher by the $+\ r_{outer}^2\ $ - term when compared to a solid cylinder. This finding is then underpinned by an experiment of a hollow and a solid cylinder rolling down an incline, showing exactly that: The moment of inertia is higher for the hollow cylinder.

The $+\ r_{outer}^2\ $ - term is the only difference between the two formulas and without further comment, we might have *quietly (and erroneously) assumed the two cylinders in question are identical except the hollow cylinder has some mass removed radially, out from the center*. A look at the ansatz, something like the following:

$\int\limits_{{cyl}}r^2 \ dm\ =\ \frac{m}{V_{cyl}}\iiint\limits_{V_{cyl}}r^2\ dV\ =\ ...$

shows there is no normalization to mass. These integrals really amount to the sum of all infinitesimal mass elements multiplied by their radii squared. So how could they possibly yield a higher value for a hollow cylinder than for the same object except the latter has less mass?

The answer is, of course, that a normalization to mass was done after the derivation, when just the $+\ r_{outer}^2$ - term was removed from the formula for $I_{hollow\ cylinder}$. This results in a *higher density* for the hollow cylinder because the volume was reduced but the mass was left unchanged. This is only implicitly stated and might quite easily get overlooked.

For the case of "corresponding" cylinders, by which I mean the hollow cylinder has the same density, in addition to the same height and outer radius, the mass is lower and this lack of mass *overcompensates* the $+\ r_{outer}^2$ - term and it does so for all ratios $\frac{r_{inner}}{r_{outer}}$. Here is a Desmos-plot of the ratio of the respective moments of inertia for this case (i.e. same height, same outer radius, same and constant density $\rightarrow\ $lower mass of the hollow cylinder):

$\frac{I_{hollow\ cylinder}}{I_{solid\ cylinder}}=\frac{\frac{m_h}2\ (r_{outer}^2\ +\  r_{inner}^2)}{\frac{m_s}2\ r_{outer}^2}\ =\ \frac{\frac{1}2\ (height\ \cdot\ ρ\ \cdot\ 4π\ \cdot\ (r_{outer}^2\ -\ r_{inner}^2))\ \cdot\ (r_{outer}^2\ +\ r_{inner}^2)}{\frac{1}2\ (height\ \cdot\ ρ\ \cdot\ 4π\ \cdot\ (r_{outer}^2))\ \cdot\ (r_{outer}^2)}$

[image]

Note that here, the masses are named differently. This graph shows that, obviously, the moment of inertia is always lower for a hollow cylinder if nothing but the inner radius is changed and this applies analogously to a hollow vs. a solid sphere and other similar cases.

Of course, for objects with the same mass which is, on average, located at a higher distance to the rotation axis, the moment of inertia is higher and this was correctly stated in the beginning. But I think it is quite easy to miss that the hollow cylinder in the first comparison is not just a "carved-out version" of the solid cylinder.

Comment: The further the mass is from the axis of rotation, the higher $I$ is (all other things being equal)